# MySQL MATCH in column select or in where clause. Is there a difference?

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search

What is the difference, if any, in these two MySQL statements? Is there a performance difference if I use `MATCH` in the `WHERE` clause, or is it unnecessary?

```
SELECT `column`, MATCH(`column`) AGAINST ("searchterm") AS `rank` 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `rank` DESC;
```

AND

```
SELECT `column`, MATCH(`column`) AGAINST ("searchterm") AS `rank` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH(`column`) AGAINST ('searchterm') 
ORDER BY `rank` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example runs a table-scan. This must examine every row in your table, even those that don't match the pattern in your AGAINST() predicate.

The second example examines only matching rows (I assume you have defined a fulltext index).

Performance is mostly proportional to examined rows, so the second example should be much better.

Or course there are edge cases, e.g. if "searchterm" occurs on virtually every row. But I'm assuming a typical case, where your search matches a small subset of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the `WHERE` clause is for filtering -- show the rows that match; skip the others.

Anything in the `SELECT` clause is displayed for every row that matched.

`WHERE MATCH...` -- MATCH is essentially a boolean in this context -- for filtering.

`SELECT MATCH ...` provides the relevancy number that *crudely* says how "good" the match was.

`SELECT  ... WHERE MATCH ...` -- just show the rows that match.  (This is probably the most useful.  Note:  The rows are, by default, ordered by relevance.

`SELECT MATCH ... WHERE MATCH ...` -- filter and show the number, which will be 0 for non-matching rows.

`FULLTEXT` is, in most cases, much faster than `WHERE column LIKE '%searchterm%'`

Answer (score 0):

From a performance standpoint, there might be a slight difference, but it's typically minimal, and the choice between the two depends on your specific use case:

- If you want to retrieve search results with their relevance scores, the first statement is more suitable.
- If you only want rows that match the search term and don't need to retrieve the relevance scores, the second statement is more appropriate.

Both statements will return the same search results, but the second one may be slightly more efficient in filtering out non-matching rows.

Comment: Both examples will return a match score as rank.

Comment: Leaving off the `ORDER BY` will still sort by "rank".